# Register contracts-repositories from different unreferenced assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have separate projects for

1. Contracts (interfaces for repositories)
2. Repositories (implementations for contracts)
3. BusinessContracts (interfaces for business)
4. Business (implementation for BusinessContracts)
5. Web (Only BusinessContracts will be referenced - MVC project)

Castle windsor is installed in Web project.
I want to register all the dependencies (Contracts, BusinessContracts, etc..)  in web project installer. But, i am unable to do that without adding references in web project.

I dont want to add any unnecessary/extra references to my web project just to register dependencies.

So, what approach and how should i do this?
1. Having separate installers in dlls. (but how to call the ohter installers without reference to the assembly).
2. or register all the dependencies in 1 installer in web project.

I have tried both the ways but invain, I am unable to register without assembly references.

Looking for a solution to this.
Thank you.

Comment: what is the problem with assembly references?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add these references to web project. There is nothing bad in this solution, because web project is the root of your application and its execution starts from here. So go ahead with adding references to web project. This is how DI works in such apps

In every application there is place where all dependencies are resolved. It can be `Main()` method in console apps or another place in WPF app. In ASP.NET MVC this place is controller factory. From this point execution of application logic starts. When you create controller instance in runtime you should resovle all its dependencies, but DI-container can't resolve types that are not accessible. So you need all necessary assemblies to be referenced in the root app (you mvc project)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a build step to copy the unreferenced assembiles to Web project output folder, you can make Castle Windsor to do the rest of the work.

```
windsorContainer.Install(FromAssembly.Named("SomeAssembly"));
```

Castle Windsor will find the installers in SomeAssembly.dll and register the components for you. This requires that you reference Castle Windsor in other assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency Injection is highly used with plug-in technologies.  With that being said, I disagree that assemblies must be referenced at design-time.  Take a look at [How to use Castle.Windsor in an assembly loaded using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510693/how-to-use-castle-windsor-in-an-assembly-loaded-using-reflection).

Comment: Plug-ins is a very specific case. There is no need to avoid references in a root project (except specific requirements). Anyway you need name or path to the assembly somewhere in project which resolves all the types. What are the advantages over referencing assemblies directly?

Comment: @ArtemPrudnikov To your point, there are no advantages.  I just disagreed that assemblies MUST be used.

Comment: Okay, maybe i've used wrong word for this. I've meant it's okay to reference assemblies until your application requires the opposite

Answer (score 0):

You can create installers in each project where required(Using IWindsorInstaller interface). then at the starting of calling assembly (like app start in web project) install them using

```
IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Install(FromAssembly.InThisApplication());
```

This will work for you.